# R Caret - Random Forest with repeated CV

Tags: r, cross-validation, random-forest, caret, bagging

I am currently struggling to explain the combination of bagging and cross-validation. I am aware of what each does separately but I have difficulties to explain how they are combined (if at all).

For example, if you train a model:

```
myTrainingControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                                  number = 10,                   
                                  repeats = 3,                 
                                  savePredictions = TRUE,
                                  classProbs = TRUE,
                                  verboseIter = TRUE,
                                  search = "grid")


set.seed(123)

model_rf <- train(X ~ .,
                  method = 'rf',
                  metric = "Accuracy",             
                  trControl = myTrainingControl,       
                  importance = TRUE                 
                  )
```

If you specify a model this way are the trees build based on the bootstrapped samples (In-bag part)? Or a combination of bootstrapping and cross-validation or are they just used at different stages?

I am a little bit lost here and could not find any explanation in the caret documentation.

Comment: They are separate, first you split into k folds, and then train each mold based on it's own fold, so the bootstrapping is done inside the fold.

Comment: Cross-validation acts on a single estimation algorithm (a map from the data to predictions). Random-forests are just another estimation algorithm. Internally, it uses bagging but it still just maps data to predictions and can be cross-validated in the usual way.